# Set html and text both to an element on same time with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i how can set text and html both to an existing element. When i click on `div` text and html both should be set to `h1` tag. i tried like this but it is not working. Expected output like this thanks!
 `<h1 id="brandBtn"><span class='text-danger'>Name</span>Apple</h1>`

```
<div id="category">
  sometext
  <h1 id="brandBtn"></h1>
</div>

$("#category").onClick(function(){
  $("#brandBtn").html("<span class='text-danger'>Name</span>:").text("Apple")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change to this: using append instead text

```
    $("#category").on("click", function(){
      $("#brandBtn").html("<span class='text-danger'>Name</span>:").append("Apple")
    });
```

Comment: thanks it worked , but why does not it works with text ?

Comment: with text this part will be overwrited(<span class='text-danger'>Name</span>:)